# Mysql query forward and back

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering what is command for database query that is querying data forward or back between rows?  Just like forward and back button. Can someone give me an example? Thanks.

For examp:

```
$sql_xxxx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE id='$xxx'") or die  (mysql_error());
$row_xxxx = mysql_fetch_array($sql_xxxx);
```

Now I need the two same query but for one forward and in the other backward the data.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question somewhat.

Comment: Do you need a MySQL command that will get the row after a certain row, or a PHP function that will get the next row in a query result, or something else?

Comment: explain more , you want to switch between queries ?

Comment: There is no forward and back button in mysql. It's not clear what you ask about, so you should give your question some love if you'd like to keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged PHP and MySQL I think I can guess what you are trying to do;

Usually you can control this with the ID of a record in MySQL, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 1;
```

In PHP, you can construct dynamic queries to get different results while just changing the value of a variable.

Lets say we now want to take the same query and make it dynamic:

```
$id = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = $id ";
```

as long as you execute this query, it will give you the row with ID = 1 , cause now it is taking the value from the $id variable.

If you want the next row, then you execute the same query but now $id must have the next value.

```
$id = 2;
```

Having a "NEXT" and "BACK" button can be matter of just adding or substracting 1 to the $id variable.
Still, this is only an example. In most of the cases you should not play with id's like that cause you should not assume that all id's exist, remember that "DELETE" exist;

So you can try to execute better a little query to find the next value like this:

to go foward:

```
$query= "SELECT MIN(ID) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID > $id"
// This will get you for sure the closest id next to the current one

and to go back:
$query= "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID < $id"
```

I hope this helps,

Regards

Comment: I'm glad, don't forget to rate. I don't like helping people, I'm here just for the rates. LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `LIMIT` in your query, which results in a specific number of rows. For instance, when you end your query with `LIMIT 100, 10`, you will get 10 results starting at row 100.

This way, you can build prev/next buttons, that when clicked, retrieve the previous or next page of results.

But in most other cases, you will just query everything you need and run through the result set. You do this by querying the result, and [fetching](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) each next row of the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `LIMIT` keyword, the database will happily return a "page" of data, for example;

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_time LIMIT 40,20;  -- will return rows 41-60.
```

You can make use of that from PHP by just setting the first `LIMIT` number to `page number * page size` and the second number to `page size` (with page number being 0 for the first page). In the example, the page size would be 20 and the page number would be 2 (the third page) and the results will be all the posts from the third page.

There's nothing more to it from the database side, you'll just have to make good use of it from PHP.

Comment: yes something like that, the thing is that script needs to go for one forward or and for one back

Comment: @Reddwarf MySQL won't keep track of what page is viewed by each user, you will have to handle that in PHP. For example, you could create a URL like `http://mysite/viewposts.php?page=1` and read the page parameter from the `$_GET[]` collection in PHP and pass it as page number to the database as mentioned above. If anyone presses "next page", just make that link go to `http://mysite/viewposts.php?page=2`.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding the question correctly, it sounds like you're trying to implement pagination in your queries and you would utilize the 'limit' clause, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

here's more [documentation](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-to-use-LIMIT-clause-in-MySQL)

Comment: Yes you have understand me, but I need just one record forward and in the other query one record back